# How to use multiple as keyword in an ngIf expression?

Tags: angular

I have a `note$` `Observable` in my component as follows:

```
this.note$ = this.serverService.makeGetReq({url:"some_url"})
```

`note$` is of type `Observable<{body:INote, errorCode:string}>`

In my template:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="(note$|async).body as note">...</div>
```

But I am getting follwing error when `note$` resolves to `null`:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null
```

To avoid above error, I did following:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="(note$|async) as value &&  value.body as note">...</div>
```

But I got an error:

```
ng: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
```

My guess is, this is an unhelpful error message cause by using two `as` keywords in the same expression

How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  <div class="container" *ngIf="(note$|async)?.body as note">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **`safe navigation operator`** in this case to handle null even though you are using async on the notes$. however i do not think body is needed.

```
  <div class="container" *ngIf="(note$|async)?.body as note">...</div>
```

this should be it,

```
<div *ngIf="note$| async as notes" class="notes-zone" >
```

Comment: Thanks. `.body` is coming from the server. I have no control. Can you explain your second snippet? What is @fade?

Comment: that was just a class :)